# Use fewest batches to send documents of varying sizes

Tags: java, algorithm

Got a bit of an interesting one here.

We have a system that gets metadata about a bunch of documents, one piece of which is their size. In order to cut down on the time it takes to process any given request we want to split up these documents into request batches of 10MB max.

At the moment I'm just iterating over the list and adding the size to a value, and after that value hits 10MB we cut off the batch at the previous document and then continue on.

However in this case we could end up with super small batches due to the order of documents. Example:
Doc 1: 1MB
Doc 2: 10MB
Doc 3: 1MB

In this case we end up with 3 requests because 1MB + 10MB is over the cap, so we cut the first request at document 1. Then 10MB + 1 MB is over the cap again, so we cut the second request at document 2.

Is there a way to look over a set of values and see if there's a generally better way to split them up so that there are fewer batches but the batches stay under a certain cap? I imagine I'm approaching something along the lines of a classic algorithm problem here, just not sure if this is a solved one or not.

Comment: Are you forced to send the metadata in order?  I reckon you just sort the list based on size.

Comment: Box Packing / Knapsack Packing - that's one of the more common names for this classic problem. Searching on that will bring up a number of heuristic algorithms.

Comment: @Andrew another keyword would be bin packing.

Comment: And no we're not required to send the metadata in order. I wasn't sure if sorting based on size would be equally bad, as we hit a point where we're packing 5MB docs in on their own request even though they could be paired with smaller documents.

Comment: Write a simple mapReduce to Group anything that's < 10 MB in one group and anything more than that in another group and then process them, that way you can avoid smaller batches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html to get a priority queue in Java.  So we can make `batches` be a priority queue of batches, making the least full batch easy to get with a method that I'll call `batches.pop()`, and you can add a batch with `batches.add(...)`.  With that, here is pseudocode for a good heuristic for your problem.

```
Initialize empty batches data structure
batches.add(new Batch())

Sort documents from largest to smallest

for each document in documents:
    batch = batches.pop()
    if batch.size() + document.size() < cap:
        batch.add(document)
        batches.add(batch)
    else:
        batches.add(batch)
        newBatch = new Batch()
        newBatch.add(document)
        batches.add(newBatch)

while not batches.isEmpty():
    send batches.pop()
```

Comment: Poking around I found https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html.  If you use that, you can use something like `batches.headMap(capacity - document.size()).lastKey()` to find the fullest batch that the given document can go into, rather than just putting it into the emptiest.  That is likely to be a significantly better packing.  However there are a number of complications to sort through, such as having multiple batches  with the same capacity.  But it is a better algorithm.